# Unable to run Application.groovy from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, grails-3.0

I have a new grails 3 project that I created using the `grails create-app` command. When I try to run `Application.main()` from IntelliJ IDEA I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at grails.dev.Support.enableAgentIfNotPresent(Support.groovy:54)
    at grails.dev.Support$enableAgentIfNotPresent.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:114)
    at test.Application.<clinit>(Application.groovy)
    ... 3 more
```

The application starts up if I run it using `gradle bootRun`. My system is configured as follows:

```
Win 7 64 bit
IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3 community edition
Grails 3.0.1
GRAILS_HOME=D:\grails-3.0.1\bin
Java 1.8.45
JAVA_HOME=C:Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to set your `GRAILS_HOME` variable to the root of your Grails installation, not the bin folder

```
GRAILS_HOME=D:\grails-3.0.1
```